# Insert a row to Subgrid using custom button without expanding the Subgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I created Subgrid as a grid & custom button to add rows to subgrids. 
Rows are getting created if I call addRowData after clicking/expanding any sub-grids but without that I cannot insert any rows.

Is there any way to insert the rows without expanding/setting focus on the sub-grids.

**UPDATED**

Process flow:

1. We have created a Grid & reach row of the grid has sub-grid.
2. Grid has custom buttons to Add & Save row data in Sub-grid.
3. Now if user clicks on Add row button then we are taking the user to a custom page where user input the required data.
4. On save (in the same custom page) we are creating a new row to the respective sub-grid.

I created the sub-grid as grid & in both I used datatype as "JSON".

Set the subgridoption to this - subGridOptions:{expandOnLoad: false,selectOnExpand : false,reloadOnExpand : false}

Invoking the gridComplete on click of our custom button addRow:

```
gridComplete: function(){ 
$("#addRow").click(function(e) {                        
var rowIds = $("#list2").getDataIDs();
    $.each(rowIds, function (index, rowId) {
        //Dynamically expanding it so that we can add new rows 
        $("#list2").expandSubGridRow(rowId);                    
    });
});               
}
```

Code in subGridRowExpanded :

```
    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridId, rowId) {                  
        var selr = jQuery('#list2').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
        var apid = jQuery('#list2').jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'ActionPlanId');
        var subgridTableId;
        subgridTableId = subgridId + "_t";
        jQuery("#" + subgridId).html("<table id='" + subgridTableId + "' class='scroll'></table>");
        jQuery("#" + subgridTableId).jqGrid({
        url: 'SomeServiceurl',
        datatype: "json",
        jsonReader: {
            root: function (obj) {
            return obj;
            },
            repeatitems: false
        },
        serializerGridData: function (postData) {
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        },
        colNames: [
                    'UniqueId',
                    'Column1',
                    'Column2',
                    'Column3',
                  ],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'UniqueId', index: 'UniqueId', width: 100, hidden: true },                      
                    { name: 'Column1', index: 'Column1', width: 100 },
                    { name: 'Column2', index: 'Column2', width: 200 },
                    { name: 'Column3', index: 'Column3', width: 80, editable: true, editrules: { required: true, minValue: 1 }, align: "center" }
                  ],

        height: "auto",
        loadonce: true,
        rowNum: 20,
        editurl: 'clientArray',
        cellsubmit: 'clientarray',
        onSelectRow: function (subgridId) {
        var $this = $(this), p = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam"), rowData
        rowData = $this.jqGrid("getRowData", subgridId);            
    },
    });
```

},

Pseudo code of function which we are calling on click of addRow button:

```
    var addtrowdetails = function () 
    {
        //Getting the data
        var data = [
                    [
                        Column1,
                        Column2,
                        Column3
                    ]
        ];
        var names =
                    [
                        "Column1",
                        "Column2",
                        "Column3"
                    ];

        //Assigning the data to myNewRowData 

        //Adding the rows
        for (var i = LastCount1; i <= LastCount1; i++) {
            $("#list2_" + subGridNo + "_t").jqGrid('addRowData', LastCount1, myNewRowData[i],'last');
        }

        //Incrementing the position for next use
        LastCount1 += 1;

    }
```

Comment: I have resolved this with a workaround, I am expanding the Sub-grids on gridComplete but can any one tell me is this the only way to achieve this?

Comment: you should post more details about what you do. The usage of `addRowData` is almost always the bad way. The usage of `gridComplete` I don't recommend too. You should post **always** which `datatype` you use in grid and subgrid, whether yo use `loadonce: true` or not, you should post the code of `subGridRowExpanded` and describe **where** (from which source) you get the data for subgrid.

Comment: @Oleg Excuse me for incomplete information. I have updated my query back again. I also want to know the best approach as I told I just found a workaround.... Danke Schön.